# Kotlin actor to actor communication

Tags: kotlin, actor, kotlinx.coroutines

An actor can be sent a message with `actor.send()` or `actor.offer()`
Once my actor gets the message from its channel I'd like to return a response. How do I do this? I don't see any obvious built in method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to request the `Actor`’s `channel`,
as [documented](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels/actor.html):

> [The `actor` coroutine builder] Launches new coroutine that is *receiving messages from its mailbox channel* and returns a reference to the coroutine as an `ActorJob`. The resulting object *can be used to send messages* to this coroutine.

Here’s a simple [example](https://github.com/s1monw1/Kotlin_Examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/de/swirtz/kotlin/coroutines/ActorExample.kt).

Comment: So basically I have to send a callback in my message, there isn't a built in method.

Comment: Exactly, hope it helped!